# Spring boot : Kafka commits offset

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a very simple application :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "journal-topic")
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String,String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        var message = extractMessage(consumerRecord);
        messageService.saveOrUpdateMessage(message);
    }
```

`extractMessage(consumerRecord)` throws an `Exception` (`IllegalArgumentException`) but what happens is during my unit tests, there a 6 retries. I don't understand why.
I `acknowledge()` as soon as I entered the method, before the exception was thrown. So it should be considered fine, and no retry should happen I think.

Here is my config :

```
  kafka:
    topic: "journal-topic"
    properties:
      auto-create-topics-enable: true

    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: "journal-group"
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      max-poll-records: 10
      enable-auto-commit: false
    listener:
        ack-mode: manual_immediate
        concurrency: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you acknowledge the record, if you throw an exception, the default error handler will cause it to be replayed.

If you want to discard it, you need to catch the exception in the listener and not throw it to the container.

Or use a custom error handler.